# Recursive analysis of a table in oracle (not hierarchial i.e. not parent-child relationship)

Tags: sql, oracle, relational-database, nested-sets, transitive-closure-table

I have this table RC_CHAT:-

```
REFERRAL_ID   BY_OFFICE  TO_OFFICE  STATUS_ID  STATUS_DATE  CHAT_ID  PARENT_CHAT_ID

R1            KL12       KL11         3        05-01-14     C1
R1            KL12       KL13         3        06-01-14     C2
R1            KL13       KL01         3        07-01-14     C3
R1            KL11       KL12         1        08-01-14     C4       C1
R2            KL11       M001         3        09-01-14     C5
R2            M001       M002         3        10-01-14     C6
R2            M002       KL12         3        11-01-14     C7       
R2            M002       M001         3        11-01-14     C8       C6
R2            M001       KL11         3        11-01-14     C9       C5
```

In this scenario, different offices communicate, discuss and decide(GRANT/DENY) concerned case(s) (each case uniquely identified by REFERRAL_ID). CHAT_ID is unique for every reply irrespective of the case. An office can either reply as a fresh message or as a reply to some earlier reply. PARENT_CHAT_ID will be null in former case while it would have the CHAT_ID of the immediate parent in the latter case.

The purpose of my application is to display all the cases in which an office is involved to that office upon logging in. The problem here is that we have millions of cases, multiplying to multi million replies. So, for ease of user access and interactivity I have to organize and categorize the cases for proper redressal of every case not making it an headache for the end user.

```
I have currently organized the cases into:-

1. Fresh (A case on which no reply has been posted by an office)
2. Under Process (A case on which a reply has been posted by an office but not granted/denied)
3. Disposed (A case which is granted/denied by an office). [STATUS_ID=1(Grant)/2(Deny)] 
P.S.:- 3-Normal Message
```

Conditions:- A case at a point of time will be in different tabs for different offices.

In above example, case **R1** will appear in:-
"Fresh" for KL01.
"Under Process" for KL12,KL13.
"Disposed" for KL11.

Case **R2** will appear in:-
"Fresh" for KL12.
"Under Process" for M001,M002,KL11.
"Disposed" for none.

Like this, all the million cases are to be analysed and put into repective tabs in tabular format.

**WHAT I EXPECT:** The million or so cases should be sorted and displayed for various offices into appropriate tabs(Fresh, Under Process, Disposed) according to above given conditions.

**MY QUESTION:** What table structure or querying should I use to allow for this analysis is minimal time and cost?
I have gone through various techniques available - Nesting sets, Connect By...Prior and others. But I am still clueless of their feasibility to my problem.

Comment: At minimum, you need to post what you've tried so far, plus the desired query results.   Does record `C4` have what appears to be _both_ statuses?  It looks like this table is slightly denormalized - ie `STATUS_ID` should probably be part of referrals, not the messages talking about them.  **R2** is never referred to by KL12.  Do you need different statuses for each message, or would one per referral id work instead?  What's the type of `STATUS_DATE`, and if not date/time/timestamp, the format?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse My mistake. I have edited the question now. Now KL12 record exists.
STATUS_ID will have only one value at a time.

I need STATUS_ID message wise, because this is what helps me differentiate Fresh/Under Process/Disposed.

STATUS_DATE is of timestamp type.